# How can a text input can trigger such an expensive layout computation?

Tags: css, performance, css-grid

We have encounter some performance issue with CSS Grid and we haven't succeeded in finding the root cause. In one minimal use case showing this issue, when the user type a single character in a text field, it causes a massive layout computation which slow down the typing experience. We believed that the issue came from our JavaScript code but even with all the JavaScript removed from our example, the issue remain. It seems to be related mainly to CSS Grid.

We have created a small example on Codepen which shows the issue: https://codepen.io/sbegaudeau/pen/abOLyJG

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>

      <div id="root">
      <div class="app">
        <div class="view">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
              <div class="outer">

                <div class="inner">
                  <div class="section">
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="innerContent">
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 1
                        </button>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 2
                        </button>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 3
                        </button>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 4
                        </button>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 5
                        </button>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 6
                        </button>
                        <button class="button action" type="button">
                          Action 7
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="section">
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="radiogroup">
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice1" />Choice 1</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice2" checked=""/>Choice 2</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="radiogroup">
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice1" />Choice 1</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice2" checked=""/>Choice 2</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="radiogroup">
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice1" />Choice 1</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice2" checked=""/>Choice 2</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="radiogroup">
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice1" />Choice 1</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice2" checked=""/>Choice 2</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="radiogroup">
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice1" />Choice 1</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice2" checked=""/>Choice 2</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sectionContent">
                      <div class="radiogroup">
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice1" />Choice 1</label>
                        <label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="choice2" checked=""/>Choice 2</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
.button {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 90px;
  padding: 8px 32px;
}

.radiogroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.radio {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  column-gap: 8px;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(min-content);
}

.section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: 32px;
  gap: 32px;
}

.sectionContent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  gap: 16px;
}

.innerContent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.view {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 960px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 64px 1fr;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;

  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.outer {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-colums: 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

Try typing a single character in the text field with the Chrome Devtools performance monitoring and you can see that typing that single character triggers a 50ms layout (see the screenshot below). In our complex example, it can take more than 100ms to type a single character which is really noticeable.

What are we doing that make this so expensive?

[image: Screenshot of the performance issue on Codepen]